# How to make the view bigger in interface builder - iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Im using a scroll view and need to make the view bigger so I can add the content that appears lower down but IB does allow me to do this?

Comment: The size of the view is greyed out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the view, and then choose Tools > Size Inspector.
Then change anything you want, basically.

Comment: thanks, but the size for the view is greyed out so it wont let me select it?

Comment: Maybe you should drag a custom view over the already present view. As IB always has this standard view. Drag a new one over the default one and then repeat my instructions above

Comment: So the "solution" is to always put VIEWS on top of VIEWS?
Is that REALLY the only way to ever have a resize area?

Comment: well, no. Have you tried:
myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:newFrame];
myScrollView.contentSize = newSize;
[myScrollView addSubview:waveView];
[myContentView addSubview:myScrollView];
[myScrollView release];